# MySQL LEFTJOIN queries

Tags: mysql

I need some assistance building this query correctly. I pretty much typed out what I'm trying to do. Its not the best example but it a start at explaining. if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

```
SELECT 
    entry_id,
    author_id,
    title,
    status
FROM exp_channel_titles
WHERE title LIKE %Member Package% 
AND status = 'complete'

LEFTJOIN
SELECT
    entry_id, 
    field_id_14,
    field_id_15,
    field_id_25,
    field_id_27, 
    field_id_28, 
    field_id_29, 
    field_id_30,
    field_id_31,
    field_id_32,
    field_id_33,
    field_id_34,
    field_id_35
FROM exp_channel_data
WHERE entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id

LEFTJOIN
SELECT   
    member_id,
    email
FROM exp_members
WHERE member_id = exp_channel_titles.author_id
```

Comment: I have *no* idea what the actual question is here.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    entry_id,
    author_id,
    title,
    status
FROM exp_channel_titles

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT
    entry_id, 
    field_id_14,
    field_id_15,
    field_id_25,
    field_id_27, 
    field_id_28, 
    field_id_29, 
    field_id_30,
    field_id_31,
    field_id_32,
    field_id_33,
    field_id_34,
    field_id_35
FROM exp_channel_data
WHERE entry_id = exp_channel_titles.entry_id)

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT   
    member_id,
    email
FROM exp_members
WHERE member_id = exp_channel_titles.author_id)

WHERE title LIKE %Member Package% 
AND status = 'complete'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `LEFT JOIN` the tables like so:

```
SELECT 
    t.entry_id, t.author_id, t.title, t.status
    d.field_id_14, d.field_id_15, d.field_id_25, d.field_id_27, d.field_id_28, d.field_id_29, 
    d.field_id_30, d.field_id_31, d.field_id_32, d.field_id_33, d.field_id_34, d.field_id_35,
    m.member_id, m.email
FROM exp_channel_titles t
LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data d on t.entry_id = d.entry_id
LEFT JOIN exp_members m on t.author_id = m.author_id
WHERE t.title LIKE %Member Package% 
  AND t.status = 'complete'
```